# Email templates from admin

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, email-templates

I have this strange issue with the Magento Transactional Emails.
I have the same files on my local, development and production servers.

From ***Admin > System > Transactional Emails > Add new template***

I select a template from the drop down, leave the local to English US. The fields are not populated on development and production servers but it's working correctly on local. I thought it was a permission error but after inspection, I found out that the ajax call loading the code from the template file is working correctly:

What can be wrong?

```
/index.php/admin/system_email_template/defaultTemplate/key/7ac9c5866202e5cb29be84299bf2ebad/?isAjax=true
Response: 

{
    "template_type": 2,
    "template_subject": "{{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Shipment # {{var shipment.increment_id}} update",
    "orig_template_variables": "{\"store url=\\\"\\\"\":\"Store Url\",\"var logo_url\":\"Email Logo Image Url\",\"var logo_alt\":\"Email Logo Image Alt\",\"htmlescape var=$billing.getName()\":\"Guest Customer Name\",\"var order.increment_id\":\"Order Id\",\"var order.getStatusLabel()\":\"Order Status\",\"var comment\":\"Order Comment\",\"var store.getFrontendName()\":\"Store Name\"}",
    "template_styles": "body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px\/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }",
    "template_text": "\n\n\n\n<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,n,e){function r(e){if(!n[e]){var o=n[e]={exports:{}};t[e][0].call(o.exports,function(n){var o=t[e][1][n];return r(o?o:n)},o,o.exports)}return n[e].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<e.length;o++)r(e[o]);return r}({D5DuLP:[function(t,n){function e(t,n){var e=r[t];return e?e.apply(this,n):(o[t]||(o[t]=[]),void o[t].push(n))}var r={},o={};n.exports=e,e.queues=o,e.handlers=r},{}],handle:[function(t,n){n.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,n){function e(){var t=l.info=NREUM.info;if(t&&t.agent&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&p&&p.body){l.proto="https"===f.split(": ")[0]||t.sslForHttp?"https: //":"http: //",i("mark",["onload",a()]);var n=p.createElement("script");n.src=l.proto+t.agent,p.body.appendChild(n)}}function r(){"complete"===p.readyState&&o()}function o(){i("mark",["domContent",a()])}function a(){return(new Date).getTime()}var i=t("handle"),u=window,p=u.document,s="addEventListener",c="attachEvent",f=(""+location).split("?")[0],l=n.exports={offset:a(),origin:f,features:[]};p[s]?(p[s]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),u[s]("load",e,!1)):(p[c]("onreadystatechange",r),u[c]("onload",e)),i("mark",["firstbyte",a()])},{handle:"D5DuLP"}],loader:[function(t,n){n.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}]},{},["G9z0Bl"]);</script><body style=\"background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;\">\n<div style=\"background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;\">\n<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\">\n<tr>\n    <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" style=\"padding:20px 0 20px 0\">\n        <!-- [ header starts here] -->\n        <table bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\" border=\"0\" width=\"650\" style=\"border:1px solid #E0E0E0;\">\n            <tr>\n                <td valign=\"top\" style=\"background-color: #f4f4f4; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"{{store url=\"\"}}\"><img src=\"{{var logo_url}}\" alt=\"{{var logo_alt}}\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\" border=\"0\"\/><\/a><\/td>\n            <\/tr>\n            <!-- [ middle starts here] -->\n            <tr>\n                <td valign=\"top\">\n                    <h1 style=\"color: #f47321; font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;\">Dear {{htmlescape var=$billing.getName()}},<\/h1>\n                    <p style=\"font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;\">\n                        Your order # {{var order.increment_id}} has been <br\/>\n                        <strong>{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}<\/strong>.\n                    <\/p>\n                    <p style=\"font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;\">{{var comment}}<\/p>\n                    <p style=\"font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;\">\n                        If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at\n                        <a href=\"mailto:{{config path='trans_email\/ident_support\/email'}}\" style=\"color:#1E7EC8;\">{{config path='trans_email\/ident_support\/email'}}<\/a>\n                        or by phone at {{config path='general\/store_information\/phone'}}.\n                    <\/p>\n                <\/td>\n            <\/tr>\n            <tr>\n                <td bgcolor=\"#f4f4f4\" align=\"center\" style=\"background:#f4f4f4; text-align:center;\"><center><p style=\"font-size:12px; margin:0;\">Thank you again, <strong style=\"color: #f47321;\">{{var store.getFrontendName()}}<\/strong><\/p><\/center><\/td>\n            <\/tr>\n        <\/table>\n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n<\/table>\n<\/div>\n<\/body>",
    "template_id": "sales_email_shipment_comment_guest_template",
    "orig_template_code": "sales_email_shipment_comment_guest_template",
    "template_variables": "{\"label\":\"Template Variables\",\"value\":[{\"value\":\"{{store url=\\\"\\\"}}\",\"label\":\"Store Url\"},{\"value\":\"{{var logo_url}}\",\"label\":\"Email Logo Image Url\"},{\"value\":\"{{var logo_alt}}\",\"label\":\"Email Logo Image Alt\"},{\"value\":\"{{htmlescape var=$billing.getName()}}\",\"label\":\"Guest Customer Name\"},{\"value\":\"{{var order.increment_id}}\",\"label\":\"Order Id\"},{\"value\":\"{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}\",\"label\":\"Order Status\"},{\"value\":\"{{var comment}}\",\"label\":\"Order Comment\"},{\"value\":\"{{var store.getFrontendName()}}\",\"label\":\"Store Name\"}]}",
    "orig_template_used_default_for": [

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

we wrote a module to work around this issue, you can find it under the Aligent organization at Github: https://github.com/aligent/Aligent_NewRelicFix - please let us know if you experience any further issues with it.

Comment: greats answer,:0

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue on one of the my project I am working on and figured out why this is happening, so I am posting it here, so it can be useful to others.

- In the live site it is not loading some of the default email templates at the time of creating new template based on them, but it is working on my local site perfectly.
- So, I have compared both the ajax responses I am getting, and came to know in the live site below script is added at the begining of the response, which cause this issue.

## Script which cause the issue:

```
    (window.NREUM || (NREUM = {})).loader_config = {xpid:"UgcCVVFTGwcDV1lXDwk="};
window.NREUM || (NREUM = {}), __nr_require = function(t, e, n) {
    function r(n) {
if (!e[n]) {
var o = e[n] = {exports: {}};
t[n][0].call(o.exports, function(e) {
var o = t[n][1][e];
return r(o ? o : e)
}, o, o.exports)
}
return e[n].exports
}
if ("function" == typeof __nr_require)
return __nr_require;
for (var o = 0; o < n.length; o++)
r(n[o]);
return r
}({1:[function(t, e) {
function n(t, e, n) {
n || (n = {});
for (var r = o[t], a = r && r.length || 0, s = n[i] || (n[i] = {}), u = 0; a > u; u++)
r[u].apply(s, e);
return s
}
function r(t, e) {
var n = o[t] || (o[t] = []);
n.push(e)
}
var o = {}, i = "nr@context";
e.exports = {on: r, emit: n}
}, {}], 2:[function(t) {
function e(t, e, n, i, s) {
return u ? u -= 1 : r("err", [s || new UncaughtException(t, e, n)]), "function" == typeof a ? a.apply(this, o(arguments)) : !1
}
function UncaughtException(t, e, n) {
this.message = t || "Uncaughterrorwithnoadditionalinformation", this.sourceURL = e, this.line = n
}
function n(t) {
r("err", [t, (new Date).getTime()])
}
var r = t("handle"), o = t(6), i = t(5), a = window.onerror, s = !1, u = 0;
t("loader").features.push("err"), window.onerror = e, NREUM.noticeError = n;
try {
throw new Error
} catch (d) {
"stack"in d && (t(1), t(2), "addEventListener"in window && t(3), window.XMLHttpRequest && XMLHttpRequest.prototype && XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener && t(4), s = !0)
}
i.on("fn-start", function() {
s && (u += 1)
}), i.on("fn-err", function(t, e, r) {
s && (this.thrown = !0, n(r))
}), i.on("fn-end", function() {
s && !this.thrown && u > 0 && (u -= 1)
}), i.on("internal-error", function(t) {
r("ierr", [t, (new Date).getTime(), !0])
})
}, {1:5, 2:4, 3:3, 4:6, 5:1, 6:14, handle:"D5DuLP", loader:"G9z0Bl"}], 3:[function(t) {
function e(t) {
r.inPlace(t, ["addEventListener", "removeEventListener"], "-", n)
}
function n(t) {
return t[1]
}
var r = t(1), o = (t(3), t(2));
if (e(window), "getPrototypeOf"in Object) {
for (var i = document; i && !i.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener"); )
i = Object.getPrototypeOf(i);
i && e(i);
for (var a = XMLHttpRequest.prototype; a && !a.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener"); )
a = Object.getPrototypeOf(a);
a && e(a)
} else
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener") && e(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
o.on("addEventListener-start", function(t) {
if (t[1]) {
var e = t[1];
"function" == typeof e ? this.wrapped = e["nr@wrapped"] ? t[1] = e["nr@wrapped"] : e["nr@wrapped"] = t[1] = r(e, "fn-") : "function" == typeof e.handleEvent && r.inPlace(e, ["handleEvent"], "fn-")
}
}), o.on("removeEventListener-start", function(t) {
var e = this.wrapped;
e && (t[1] = e)
})
}, {1:15, 2:1, 3:14}], 4:[function(t) {
var e = (t(3), t(1)), n = t(2);
e.inPlace(window, ["requestAnimationFrame", "mozRequestAnimationFrame", "webkitRequestAnimationFrame", "msRequestAnimationFrame"], "raf-"), n.on("raf-start", function(t) {
t[0] = e(t[0], "fn-")
})
}, {1:15, 2:1, 3:14}], 5:[function(t) {
function e(t) {
var e = t[0];
"string" == typeof e && (e = new Function(e)), t[0] = n(e, "fn-")
}
var n = (t(3), t(1)), r = t(2);
n.inPlace(window, ["setTimeout", "setInterval", "setImmediate"], "setTimer-"), r.on("setTimer-start", e)
}, {1:15, 2:1, 3:14}], 6:[function(t) {
function e() {
o.inPlace(this, s, "fn-")
}
function n(t, e) {
o.inPlace(e, ["onreadystatechange"], "fn-")
}
function r(t, e) {
return e
}
var o = t(1), i = t(2), a = window.XMLHttpRequest, s = ["onload", "onerror", "onabort", "onloadstart", "onloadend", "onprogress", "ontimeout"];
window.XMLHttpRequest = function(t) {
var n = new a(t);
try {
i.emit("new-xhr", [], n), o.inPlace(n, ["addEventListener", "removeEventListener"], "-", function(t, e) {
return e
}), n.addEventListener("readystatechange", e, !1)
} catch (r) {
try {
i.emit("internal-error", r)
} catch (s) {
}
}
return n
}, 
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype = a.prototype, o.inPlace(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, ["open", "send"], "-xhr-", r), i.on("send-xhr-start", n), i.on("open-xhr-start", n)
}, {1:15, 2:1}], 7:[function(t){function e(){function e(t){if ("string" == typeof t && t.length)return t.length; if ("object" != typeof t)return void 0; if ("undefined" != typeof ArrayBuffer && t instanceof ArrayBuffer && t.byteLength)return t.byteLength; if ("undefined" != typeof Blob && t instanceof Blob && t.size)return t.size; if ("undefined" != typeof FormData && t instanceof FormData)return void 0; try{return JSON.stringify(t).length} catch (e){return void 0}}function n(t){var n = this.params, r = this.metrics; if (!this.ended){this.ended = !0; for (var i = 0; u > i; i++)t.removeEventListener(s[i], this.listener, !1); if (!n.aborted){if (r.duration = (new Date).getTime() - this.startTime, 4 === t.readyState){n.status = t.status; var a = t.responseType, d = "arraybuffer" === a || "blob" === a || "json" === a?t.response:t.responseText, f = e(d); if (f && (r.rxSize = f), this.sameOrigin){var c = t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data"); c && (n.cat = c.split(",
").pop())}}else n.status=0;r.cbTime=this.cbTime,o("xhr",[n,r])}}}function r(t,e){var n=i(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+": "+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}t("loader").features.push("xhr");var o=t("handle"),i=t(1),a=t(5),s=["load","error","abort","timeout"],u=s.length,d=t(2);t(3),t(4),a.on("new - xhr",function(){this.totalCbs=0,this.called=0,this.cbTime=0,this.end=n,this.ended=!1,this.xhrGuids={}}),a.on("open - xhr - start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},r(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),a.on("open - xhr - end",function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X - NewRelic - ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),a.on("send - xhr - start",function(t,n){var r=this.metrics,o=t[0],i=this;if(r&&o){var d=e(o);d&&(r.txSize=d)}this.startTime=(new Date).getTime(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(i.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||i.called===i.totalCbs&&(i.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof n.onload))&&i.end(n)}catch(e){try{a.emit("internal - error",e)}catch(r){}}};for(var f=0;u>f;f++)n.addEventListener(s[f],this.listener,!1)}),a.on("xhr - cb - time",function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),a.on("xhr - load - added",function(t,e){var n=""+d(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),a.on("xhr - load - removed",function(t,e){var n=""+d(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),a.on("addEventListener - end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr - load - added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("removeEventListener - end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr - load - removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("fn - start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=(new Date).getTime()))}),a.on("fn - end",function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&a.emit("xhr - cb - time",[(new Date).getTime()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&e()},{1:8,2:11,3:3,4:6,5:1,handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],8:[function(t,e){e.exports=function(t){var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split(": //");return!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split(": ")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname),r.sameOrigin=!e.hostname||e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port&&e.protocol===n.protocol,r}},{}],handle:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],D5DuLP:[function(t,e){function n(t,e){var n=r[t];return n?n.apply(this,e):(o[t]||(o[t]=[]),void o[t].push(e))}var r={},o={};e.exports=n,n.queues=o,n.handlers=r},{}],11:[function(t,e){function n(t){if(!t||"object"!=typeof t&&"function"!=typeof t)return-1;if(t===window)return 0;if(o.call(t,"__nr"))return t.__nr;try{return Object.defineProperty(t,"__nr",{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(e){return t.__nr=r,r}finally{r+=1}}var r=1,o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],loader:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,e){function n(){var t=p.info=NREUM.info;if(t&&t.agent&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&u&&u.body){p.proto="https"===c.split(": ")[0]||t.sslForHttp?"https: //":"http: //",a("mark",["onload",i()]);var e=u.createElement("script");e.src=p.proto+t.agent,u.body.appendChild(e)}}function r(){"complete"===u.readyState&&o()}function o(){a("mark",["domContent",i()])}function i(){return(new Date).getTime()}var a=t("handle"),s=window,u=s.document,d="addEventListener",f="attachEvent",c=(""+location).split("?")[0],p=e.exports={offset:i(),origin:c,features:[]};u[d]?(u[d]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),s[d]("load",n,!1)):(u[f]("onreadystatechange",r),s[f]("onload",n)),a("mark",["firstbyte",i()])},{handle:"D5DuLP"}],14:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(0>o?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=n},{}],15:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,r,s){function nrWrapper(){try{var n,a=u(arguments),d=this,f=r&&r(a,d)||{}}catch(c){i([c,"",[a,d,s],f])}o(e+"start",[a,d,s],f);try{return n=t.apply(d,a)}catch(p){throw o(e+"err",[a,d,p],f),p}finally{o(e+"end",[a,d,n],f)}}return a(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[n.flag]=!0,nrWrapper)}function r(t,e,r,o){r||(r="");var i,s,u,d="-"===r.charAt(0);for(u=0;u<e.length;u++)s=e[u],i=t[s],a(i)||(t[s]=n(i,d?s+r:r,o,s,t))}function o(t,e,n){try{s.emit(t,e,n)}catch(r){i([r,t,e,n])}}function i(t){try{s.emit("internal-error",t)}catch(e){}}function a(t){return!(t&&"function"==typeof t&&t.apply&&!t[n.flag])}var s=t(1),u=t(2);e.exports=n,n.inPlace=r,n.flag="nr@wrapper"},{1:1,2:14}]},{},["G9z0Bl",2,7]);
==================================================
```

- On the live server I am using **New Relic** for site performance monitoring.
- When New Relic is enabled it adds this script code at the beginning of the email template ajax response, which cause invalid JSON syntax and because of this it stop further processing template and it will not load template content.
- I have looked for the solution and one possible way is, if we disable New Relic then email templates will work fine and once we have done with our changes we can re-enable it back.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The function that loads the email template is

`Mage_Adminhtml_System_Email_TemplateController::defaultTemplateAction()`

You can hook into an event (predispatch & co) and run:

`newrelic_disable_autorum (  )`

This tells new relic that this request will not have RUM enabled.

Another option is to disable RUM for the whole admin (really easy if you have admin on a separte web node, simple module with an event for adminhtml area, etc).

Comment: This makes sense, I have Newrelic installed on the server too. I had no idea it could mess up the site.
I'll test your solution soon.
Thanks