# Some Transactional Email Templates Won't Load

Tags: magento-enterprise, email-templates

When I go to "System -> Transactional Emails," "Add New Template" and attempt to load the "New Order" template, nothing is returned in any field in the Template Information section. It behaves this way on both stage and production. Some of the emails will load (Payment Failed, for example) but there is nothing to indicate why my most popular email templates won't load. I was already able to update one template in our store, the New Account email.

I need to make some urgent changes to this template right away (we are currently using the default template), and it would even be helpful to find the default template posted somewhere, but my searches have returned nothing. We don't have custom code or modules that directly modify this behavior, to my knowledge. Nothing shows up in htdocs/var/log/exception.log at any point during this process.

To further clarify, when I load a template that actually works (such as "Payment Failed Template") and then go back to load the "New Order" template, the information in those fields is still the Payment Failed Template information (Subject and Content). Although I get the "Please Wait" circle onscreen for about 1.5 seconds, nothing on the page changes aside from the top Template dropdown, which says New Order.

I have also verified that the file exists in htdocs/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html and am using it to build the template I need urgently.

Magento Enterprise 1.13.1.0

[image: Screenshot of empty fields]

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'nothing comes up in the Template Information section'. What do you see, partially rendered content (which would indicate where a problem may lie according to where rendering stopped), fully rendered content but no email content?  A screen shot would help.

Comment: Edited to clarify. My posts get sloppy if I haven't had coffee.

Comment: Ah right so you are seeing the layout for creating a new template.  Does the URL contain `system_email_template/edit` or `system_email_template/new`?

Comment: system_email_template/new/ because I AM using the Add New Template button. To further clarify, when I load a template that actually works (such as "Payment Failed Template") and then go back to load the "New Order" template, the information in those fields is still the Payment Failed Template information (Subject and Content). Although I get the "Please Wait" circle onscreen for about 1.5 seconds, nothing on the page changes aside from the top Template dropdown, which says New Order.

Comment: Through searching the filesystem on the server, I did just find htdocs/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html which appears to contain the right template. I can use this to make changes, but I would still like to solve the problem and post the solution for folks who browse this question in the future.

Comment: Right ok so the issue is that existing templates are not loading when you select them under template default and click load?

Comment: @JonathanHussey Correct!

Comment: ddavidn you should add all the infos in the comments to your post. Then they are way better readable.

Comment: Do you have firebug or similar to determine if the AJAX request completes and if so what comes back?

Comment: @JonathanHussey Good suggestion. Looks like the request completes, and is formatted almost identically between the ones that work and the ones that fail. The response, however, doesn't appear to come back as properly formatted JSON, although the information from the file is all in there. I'm going to examine it more closely and see if I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I am also seeing this bug in a fresh 1.13.1.0

It appears to be invalid JSON. When I run it through lint I get the following error.
```Parse error on line 6:
...\n\n\n<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),  [snip]
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'```
This is because of newrelic actually, the js that is being included into that template is from newrelic. I am looking at why its happening.

Comment: Solution for newrelic being injected:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/email-templates-from-admin

Comment: @Aepod Wow, good catch. Not sure why I missed that one. I'm sure this will fix my issue as well.