# Transactional email templates not loading

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates, transactional-mail

When I attempt to "Add New Template" for a transactional email, select a 'template' from the list, then click 'Load Template' nothing is loaded in the templtae form.  I expected there would be a template for most/all transactional mailings.

However, I'm finding that none of the 'templates' have a default template that will load into the editor.

I could have sworn I created several email messages for transactional emails this way in the past, but now no default templates will load.

This may be realted to the unanswered question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44093/some-transactional-email-templates-wont-load)

Comment: Templates are loaded from `app/locale` folder. For example, **New Order** template for en_US is taken from `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`

Comment: In my case it was newrelic causing the problem with the RUM script. Solution here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54215/3515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have files in app/locale/en_US/template/email

You should see files such as

- account_new.html
- account_new_confirmation.html
- ....
- wishlist_share.html

If not, then copy them over from a fresh copy of magento.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, all the template files were missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been resolved this issue. Just check lib\Varien\Autoload.php
replaced with newest file according to your magento version.